# After upgrading xcode to 15.1, while running flutter build ipa shows 'Application not configured for iOS'

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

While building flutter application for iOS using `flutter build ipa` command,

```
iOS 17.2 is not installed. To download and install the platform, open
Xcode, select Xcode > Settings > Platforms, and click the GET button for the required platform.
```

error is shown.
So I installed iOS 17.2, After installing tried `flutter build ipa` but the following error was shown

```
Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead
Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

So,I Upgraded the cococapods to resolve this issue using `brew install cocoapods` command

Tried installing `command line tools` and ran `flutter doctor`. Flutter doctor result showed

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS and macOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

But Xcode is already installed and working fine.

Comment: resolved the issue by running the command  ' sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools ' in terminal